# trouble looping xarray dataframe through subdirectories

Tags: python, loops, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am trying to make a big data frame by looping through sub-directories. I want to:

i) read data from all the files (with .nc extension) in the subdirectories,
ii)  select a particular chunk of it
iii) save it in a output.nc file.

```
import os
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

rootdir ='/Users/sm/Desktop/along_track_J2'

data_new=[]

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):

    for file in files:

        file_name= os.path.join(subdir, file)  

        df=xr.open_dataset(file_name)

        df['longitude'] = ((df.longitude + 180) % 360 - 180).sortby(df.longitude)

        ds=df.where((df.longitude>=-65) & (df.longitude<=-45) & (df.latitude>55), drop=True)

        data_new.append(ds)
```

Somehow xarray cannot read the file and I see the following error:

> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/Users/sm/Desktop/jason2_processing.py', wdir='/Users/sm/Desktop')
>
> File "/Users/sm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "/Users/sm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/Users/sm/Desktop/jason2_processing.py", line 18, in 
>       df=xr.open_dataset(file_name)
>
> File "/Users/sm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 320, in open_dataset
>       **backend_kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/sm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py", line 331, in open
>       ds = opener()
>
> File "/Users/sm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py", line 230, in _open_netcdf4_group
>       ds = nc4.Dataset(filename, mode=mode, **kwargs)
>
> File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2123, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.**init**
>
> File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1743, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
>
> OSError: [Errno -51] NetCDF: Unknown file format: b'/Users/sm/Desktop/along_track_J2/.DS_Store'

Can anyone please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> OSError: [Errno -51] NetCDF: Unknown file format: b'/Users/sm/Desktop/along_track_J2/.DS_Store'

You are currently looping through all files, NetCDF and other (system) files. `.DS_store` is a file created by macOS, which isn't a NetCDF file. If you only want to process NetCDF files, something like this should work:

```
...
for file in files:
    if file.split('.')[-1] == 'nc':
        file_name= os.path.join(subdir, file) 
        df = xr.open_dataset(file_name)
        ....
```

`if file.split('.')[-1] == 'nc':` (the only thing which I added) basically checks if the file extension is `.nc`, and ignores other files.

Comment: Great approach. Could something on the lines of files=glob.glob(subdir + "*.nc") be used to avoid the if loop?

Comment: Yes, I guess so, but unless you have hundreds (or more) non-NetCDF files, I'd be surprised if it gave any difference in performance (if that's what you are after?)